# Can't get image from map service in Python

Tags: python, google-maps, python-3.x

I try to get an image of map services with python.
Google static maps and mapquestapi.com are not working. When I try to retrieve a static image from an other server erverything works fine, but at the maps services, I get this error:

```
ERROR handlers: message: plugins.xxx._scan_for_triggers : coroutine
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/xxx/handlers.py", line xxx, in run_pluggable_omnibus
yield from function(*_passed)
File "/xxx/plugins/xxx.py", line 54, in _scan_for_triggers
img_id = yield from xxx._client.upload_image(img_data, filename=filename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xxx/client.py", line 472, in upload_image
upload_url = (json.loads(res1.body.decode())['sessionStatus']
KeyError: 'sessionStatus'
```

Here the code:

```
r = yield from aiohttp.request('get', img_link)
raw = yield from r.read()
img_data = io.BytesIO(raw)
filename = "xxx"
img_id = yield from xxx._client.upload_image(img_data, filename=filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. img_link was a string, including parameters.
I had to build the url with urllib.parse.urlencode